# Marker based Augmented Reality not planing properly to marker on mobile devices only

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I’m working on creating a marker based AR game using AFrame 1.2.0 and ar.js 3.3.3. The display shows 2D images of animals that the user has to “find”. The whole game functions well now, but I was running into an issue of photos appearing distorted or warped. I figured out that the issue is the marker’s plane is not being read correctly by mobile devices. The pictures below include a red cube to show the issue better. The top one is on a PC’s webcam and shows correctly the box is mounted to the marker. The bottom one shows the box is not mounted to the marker.

I figure that the issue is either mobile device’s gyroscope features or that the screen dimensions are affecting the aspect ratio of the screen.

I’ve tried a few properties on Aframe’s a-entity, such as look-controls=‘Enabled:false’ and look-controls=‘magicWindowTrackingEnabled: false’. Neither of those made a difference. I haven’t found properties within ar.js to use. Just wondering if anyone has come across this issue and found a fix.

[images planing correctly with the marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJw3R.jpg)

[images not planing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvTh5.jpg)

Comment: is it happening on a basic [arjs scene](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gftruj-arjs-basic?path=index.html%3A9%3A50) as well?

Comment: I tried removing the animals from the scene (which were populated through JavaScript and just left the basic red box in the frame and the same result is present.  So yes, I'm still having issues with it on basic scenes.

Comment: Did you try my glitch (with a basic hiro marker)?

Comment: You are my savior! I tried your glitch on both my phone and webcam and both worked perfectly.  I saw your comment about importing AR.js without nft and that appears to be the fix!  For future reference, do you know why nft support would cause this?

Comment: THANK YOU AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

arjs comes in two different, **mutually exclusive** builds - Image + location based tracking, and marker tracking ([link](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js#%EF%B8%8Farjs-has-now-an-official-documentation%EF%B8%8F)).

Importing the wrong one may/will cause incorrect behavior like the one you experience.